# Get a list of classes lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In Java 8 it looks like the lambdas of a class are kept in an array. For example, lets say we have this class:

```
public class LambdaFactory {
    public Supplier<Integer> getOne(){
        return () -> 42;
    }

    public Supplier<Integer> getTwo(){
        return () -> 128;
    }

    public Supplier<Integer> getThree(){
         return () -> 3;
    }
}
```

and then I print it out like so:

```
    System.out.println(factory.getOne());
    System.out.println(factory.getOne());
    System.out.println(factory.getTwo());
    System.out.println(factory.getThree());
```

the output will be something like

```
examples.LambdaFactory$$Lambda$1@4e515669
examples.LambdaFactory$$Lambda$1@4e515669
examples.LambdaFactory$$Lambda$2@1b9e1916
examples.LambdaFactory$$Lambda$3@ba8a1dc
```

So we can see two thing here. The same lambda called twice gives us the same lambda object (this is not the same as with anon inner classes where we could get a new one every time). We also see that they look like they are being kept in some kind of "Lambda" structure that is part of the class

My question is, can I get ahold of the lambdas in a class? I don't have any reason to do so, I just like dissecting things

Comment: What makes you think that they are in an array?

Comment: I think you're drawing false conclusions here. Anonymous inner classes often have the `$1` construct as part of their name -- it's a common idiom that class names with the dollar sign are constructed at runtime, such as when using the dynamic `Proxy` class.

Comment: I guess I don't know if its an array or what it is, but the lambdas are the same. If I do a jUnit Assert.assertSame on two suppliers from getOne it will pass, but will fail if it's an annon inner class. See https://github.com/ryber/J8Lambda/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/ObjectLifeCycle.java

Comment: Updated to take out my assumption of an array. I wish to get to the lambdas

Comment: Do you expect this to be consistent across versions of Java?  Because it won't be.

Comment: I don't expect anything really. Just curious.

Comment: Two distinct objects can easily have the same `toString()` return value. If you want to *prove* that the two method calls return the same lambda instance, why don't you use `==` to test for identity?

Comment: "The same lambda called twice gives us the same lambda object" - not always. If a lamba expression references a variable from an outer scope then a new instance is created every time the lamba is used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lambdas are created by the JRE and the way they are created is controlled by the JRE and might vary between different JRE vendors and might change in future versions.

If you want to have fun you can create a lambda at runtime which has no corresponding information within the class file:

```
import java.lang.invoke.*;

public class ManualLambda {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    MethodHandles.Lookup me=MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType t=MethodType.methodType(void.class);
    MethodType rt=MethodType.methodType(Runnable.class);
    CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
      me, "run", rt, t, me.findStatic(ManualLambda.class, "sayHello", t), t);
    MethodHandle factory=site.getTarget();
    Runnable r=(Runnable)factory.invoke();

    System.out.println("created lambda: "+r);
    r.run();
  }
  private static void sayHello() {
      System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

The code above retraces what happens when a lambda is created. But for compile-time (“real”) lambda expressions the entire thing is triggered by a single `invokedynamic` byte code instruction. The `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(…)` method is the *bootstrap* method which is called when the `invokedynamic` instruction is executed the first time. The returned `CallSite` object is permanently associated with the `invokedynamic` instruction. If the `CallSite` is a `ConstantCallSite` and its `MethodHandle` returns the same lambda object on every execution, the `invokedynamic` instruction will “produce” the same lambda instance forever.

Answer (score 2):

[The Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4)

> At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression is similar to
>   evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal
>   completion produces a reference to an object. [...]
>
> Either a new instance of a class with the properties below is
>   allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the
>   properties below is referenced.
>
> [...]
>
> These rules are meant to offer flexibility to implementations of the
>   Java programming language, in that:
>
> - **A new object need not be allocated on every evaluation.**
> - [...]

As such, it is up to a compiler or run time environment to decide what should be returned when a lambda expression is evaluated.

> My question is, can I get ahold of the lambdas in a class? I don't
>   have any reason to do so, I just like dissecting things

You can **think** of a lambda expression as any other class constant, a `String`, an integer literal, etc. These are constants that appear in the constant pool of a `.class` file. These are references to objects that are created and exist at run time. There is no way to refer to the actual objects from a class' constant pool.

In the case of a lambda, it wouldn't be helpful anyway because it might not actually be the same object.