# Convert MethodHandle to method reference (here Function)

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8, invokedynamic

```
MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, ByteBuffer.class);
MethodHandle handle = MethodHandles.publicLookup().findConstructor(type, methodType);

Function<ByteBuffer, Object> = handle; // ???
```

Is it possible to get the last assignment work? The inverted way does not work: [Is it possible to convert method reference to MethodHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649412)

Here another and copy-pastable example:

```
new Integer("123");

MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class);
MethodHandle handle = MethodHandles.publicLookup().findConstructor(Integer.class, methodType);

Function<String, Integer> function1 = Integer::new;
Function<String, Integer> function2 = handle.toLambda(); // ???
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23606688/2711488

Comment: Holger, thanks for pointing me to the LambdaMetafactory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[«This answer»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606688/2711488) contains a code example showing how to convert a `MethodHandle` to a functional `interface` implementation using the same feature, Java 8’s lambda expressions and method references use.

It’s all about calling [`LambdaMetafactory.metafactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) with the method handle, the desired interface and the name of the sole `abstract` method and required signature.

Both, the [method’s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) and [it’s class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) are very detailled.

So, for your request, example code may look like this:

```
MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(Integer.class, String.class);
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle handle = lookup.findStatic(Integer.class, "valueOf", methodType);
Function<String,Integer> f=(Function<String,Integer>)
  LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply",
    MethodType.methodType(Function.class), methodType.generic(),
    handle, methodType).getTarget().invokeExact();

System.out.println(f.apply("123"));
```

---

You have to care about the signature types here. The fourth parameter `samMethodType` refers the the method type of the raw `interface`’s functional signature, so for the raw type `Function` we must implement `Object apply(Object)` while the `instantiatedMethodType` describes the method `Integer apply(String)`. That’s why the method `.generic()` is called on the methodType for the fourth parameter which will convert `(String)Integer` to `(Object)Object`.

This is even trickier for constructors as the constructor will be looked up with a `(String)void` type while the *functional type* is the same as in the `static` method case. So for a `static` method the method’s `MethodType` matches the `MethodType` while for a constructor we have to use a different type for the lookup:

```
MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(Integer.class, String.class);
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle handle = lookup.findConstructor(
        Integer.class, MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
Function<String,Integer> f=(Function<String,Integer>)
  LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply",
    MethodType.methodType(Function.class), methodType.generic(),
    handle, methodType).getTarget().invokeExact();
```

But that’s only for completeness, for the type `Integer` you shouldn’t call the constructor but use `valueOf` method, preferably.

Comment: Thanks again! Will include that solution into the answer collection post.

Answer (score 10):

I think you'll need something like:

```
Function<ByteBuffer,Object> fn = (Function<ByteBuffer,Object>)
    MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(Function.class, handle);
```

(<strike>Usual disclaimer: Not even compiled it.</strike> Compiled it. Seems to work.)

Comment: It’s `MethodHandleProxies`, not `MethodHandlesProxy` and a Java 7 feature, but besides that, it should work.

Comment: Tried it. Works for me (when given a name before the `=`).

Comment: @Holger Found the typo when trying to compile. All of the `MethodHandle` nonsense is @Since Java SE 7.

Comment: Works. Adding it to "function4" in the solution collection.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: not “all of the `MethodHandle` nonsense”. The `LambdaMetafactory` which produces more efficient `interface` instances and is used for lambda expressions and method references exist since Java 8. The same applies to the feature of decoding a direct handle to a `MethodHandleInfo`.

Comment: Regarding performance: I benchmarked various ways of executing a simple primitive mathematical operation in a loop of 500 million iterations. Inline code: 170; direct method invocation: 170; colon-colon lambda of the method: 300; LambdaMetafactory: 300; MethodHandleProxies: 8900; java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke: 11500. So LambdaMetafactory produces something as efficient as a directly declared lambda, whereas MethodHandleProxies produces something nearly as inefficient as old-school reflection.

Comment: @ctrueden well, LambdaFactory in fact is used internally by lambdas, so it's expectable that it has comparable performance

Answer (score 1):

**Answer collection**

No handle, just the lambda:

```
Function<String, Integer> function1 = Integer::new;
System.out.println(function1.apply("1"));
```

Simple (not generic, not exact) solution:

```
MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class);
MethodHandle handle = MethodHandles.publicLookup().findConstructor(Integer.class, methodType);
Function<String, Integer> function2 = (s) -> {
  try {
    return (Integer) handle.invoke(s);
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    throw new Error(t);
  }
};
System.out.println(function2.apply("2"));
```

Using [LambdaMetafactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) from Holger

```
MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(Integer.class, String.class);
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle handle = lookup.findConstructor(Integer.class, MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
Function<String,Integer> function3 = (Function<String,Integer>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply", MethodType.methodType(Function.class), methodType.generic(), handle, methodType).getTarget().invokeExact();
System.out.println(function3.apply("3"));
```

Using [MethodHandleProxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html) from Tom Hawtin

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Function<String, Integer> function4 = (Function<String, Integer>) MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(Function.class, handle);
System.out.println(function4.apply("4"));
```

Comment: Look at my example. The difference is the call `.generic()` on the method type for `samMethodType` parameter which differs from `instantiatedMethodType`, because `Function<String, Integer>` is generic, hence the raw code must implement `Object apply(Object)` while the actual code will perform a `Integer apply(String)` action…