# How would you call a Java method that takes a lambda as an argument from the native side of JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am attempting to call a Java method which accepts a lambda as an argument. I am not in control of the Java side of the code, and am using the invocation API. I do not know how I would even start to approach this problem- from my searches, lambdas are [compile-time language artifacts of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23650686). That also links [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606688/17206534) which shows how to make a lambda at runtime. Is creating a lambda possible to do in JNI, and if so how do you pass this into a method call?

Comment: Please edit your question with the signature of the Java method you are trying to pass a lambda to.

Comment: @Botje It is an obfuscated signature so I'm not sure how much help it would be to others.

Comment: It would help because methods generally don't take "lambdas". They take objects that implement a given interface and lambdas are just a shortcut for constricting suitable objects. If we know the exact signature of the method the translation to a native method is mechanical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take `LongStream.generate` as an example target method. Its method signature is

```
static LongStream generate(LongSupplier s);
```

and `LongSupplier` is:

```
@FunctionalInterface public interface LongSupplier {
  long getAsLong();
}
```

You can implement your own `LongSupplier` on the Java side as follows:

```
package dummy.pkg;
import java.util.function.LongSupplier;
public class NativeLongSupplier implements LongSupplier {
  native public long getAsLong();
}
```

then the following C++ code will let you implement the `getAsLong` method:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong Java_dummy_pkg_NativeLongSupplier_getAsLong(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
  static uint64_t counter = 0;
  return ++counter;
}
```